# Rewriterule for PHP files fails

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I want to rewrite these **.htaccess** rules into a templates to use it for my other pages as well:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/add-news/?$ admin/add_news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/edit-news/([0-9a-z-@._]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/edit_news.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

**For example:**

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z-])/?$ admin/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z-])/([0-9a-z-@._]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/$1.php?name=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

I tested the latest rules on WAMP and it does not work. It returns: 404 Not Found error

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

**The full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^admin/add-news/?$ admin/add_news.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/edit-news/([0-9a-z-@._]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ admin/edit_news.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Files locations are:

```
1. C:\wamp64\www\test.com
2. C:\wamp64\www\test.com\admin\add_news.php
C:\wamp64\www\test.com\admin\edit_news.php
3. I want redirect from URLs with underscores to hyphens, for example:
from admin/add_news.php to admin/add-news
Also from admin/edit_news.php?name=%1&id=%2 to admin/edit-news/name/id
Example: admin/edit-news/my-news-title/2
```

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do let us know 3 things here. 1st- Where is your htaccess file present(FULL path details), 2nd- where are your .php files present(complete path please)? 3rd- What sample urls you are hitting? and FROM which sample url TO which sample url you want to rewrite/redirect? Thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
Ok. 
`1. C:\wamp64\www\test.com`
`2. C:\wamp64\www\test.com\admin\add_news.php
C:\wamp64\www\test.com\admin\edit_news.php`
`3. I want redirect from URLs with underscores to hyphens, for example:
from admin/add_news.php to admin/add-news
Also from admin/edit_news.php?name=%1&id=%2 to admin/edit-news/name/id`

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for letting info, so you are hitting link `admin/edit-news/name/id` in browser? If yes then please do add this all information in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13
Yes, browser url must be for example: `admin/edit-news/my-news-title/2`.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown attempts, please try following htaccess rules file.

Make sure that your .htaccess is present along with your admin folder AND make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

***Samples specific rules:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /test.com/
##First rule for hitting url admin/add-news in browser.
RewriteRule ^test\.com/admin/([\w-]+)/?$ admin/$1.php [QSA,NC,L]

##Second rule for hitting url admin/edit-news/name/id in browser.
RewriteRule ^test\.com/admin/([\w-]+)/([^/]*)/(\d)+/?$ admin/$1.php?name=$2&id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***Generic rules:***

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /test.com/

##First rule for hitting url admin/add-news in browser.
RewriteRule ^test\.com/admin/([^-]*)-([^/]*)/?$ admin/$1_$2.php [QSA,NC,L]

##Second rule for hitting url admin/edit-news/name/id in browser.
RewriteRule ^test\.com/admin/([^-]*)-([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d)+/?$ admin/$1_$2.php?name=$3&id=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```